# Handle text selection wp8 Webbrowser

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using WP8 webbrowser control to show an html page and xaml is like this

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
   <phone:WebBrowser  IsScriptEnabled="True" x:Name="mainBrowserControl">
            <tools:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <tools:GestureListener DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted"/>
            </tools:GestureService.GestureListener>
        </phone:WebBrowser>
</Grid>
```

What i want to do is to show an application bar when user selects some text in browser.And for doing that i listen to DragCompleted event and show the Applicationbar when some selection of text is there.The code used is

```
private void GestureListener_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        string selected_text = "";
        try
        {
          selected_text= //get selected text from browser
        }
        catch { }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selected_text.Trim()))
        {
           Show Applicationbar menus
        }
    }
```

But the problem with this approach is if user simply selects a text in browser , the default copy icon is visible but how can i show the applicationbar menu as well in the bottom(Since i am not dragging the selection , just make a selection only - more like double click) See the image attached[image]

Comment: how about listening to [DoubleTap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.doubletap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event in addition to `DragCompleted` event?

Comment: NO it wont work , if user simply selects the text DoubleTap event not firing

Answer (score 0):

First question. you can get selected content in WebBrowser via this

```
function GetSelectedText() {
   window.external.Notify(document.selection.createRange().htmlText);           
}
```

in your `GestureListener_DragCompleted` you call browser.InvokeScript("GetSelectedText");

you can get the text in browser.ScriptNotify event

Second question, I have no idea too. If you get a solution, Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: My question is about not getting text selected ( I can use javascript like you mentioned). But i am asking which event to call when user selects a text ?? DragCompleted occurs only when user drags selection , if user simply selects text what we will do?

Comment: @JMat you can use `ManipulationCompleted`